# Unmarshalling error while not using it in my code

Tags: android, unmarshalling

I'me getting Parcel Unmarshalling error in my code but i didnt use that in my code . how do i find what is causing the issue in my code ?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.quantyam.apps.rise2wake/com.quantyam.apps.rise2wake.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@b320806: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6881391 at offset 700
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

UPDATE :

I'm using Fluid slider , 
https://github.com/Ramotion/fluid-slider-android

i get the error from this

```
android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator (Parcel.java:2846)
android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:2772)
android.view.AbsSavedState.<init> (AbsSavedState.java:67)
android.view.View$BaseSavedState.<init> (View.java:25106)
android.view.View$BaseSavedState.<init> (View.java:25095)
com.ramotion.fluidslider.FluidSlider$State.<init> (FluidSlider.kt:225)
com.ramotion.fluidslider.FluidSlider$State.<init> (FluidSlider.kt:184)
    com.ramotion.fluidslider.FluidSlider$State$Companion$CREATOR$1.createFromParcel (FluidSlider.kt:189)
com.ramotion.fluidslider.FluidSlider$State$Companion$CREATOR$1.createFromParcel (FluidSlider.kt:188)
android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:2781)
```

Comment: can you add your Mainactivity code also? is that the launcher activity?

Comment: Its the launcher activity 


i updated my question